# My Redux state is not updating even-though the old an new state are not equal

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an issue with my Redux state. I have made a reducer that should update a value in an array. However, I believe to have followed all immutability principles but for some reason my state is not updating. I even added a console log to the end of my reducer comparing the old en new state and it returns false.

Have I missed something?

I am using Redux DevTools chrome plugin to check the state.

State:

```
selectedProfileId: mainProfileId,
profiles: {
    [mainProfileId]:{
        name: "Spellbook 1",
        classes: [],
        learnedSpells: {
            cantrip: [],
            first: [],
            second: [],
            third: [],
            fourth: [],
            fifth: [],
            sixth: [],
            seventh: [],
            eighth: [],
            ninth: []
        },
        spellSlots:[
            {slots: 0, used: 0},
            {slots: 0, used: 0},
            {slots: 0, used: 0},
            {slots: 0, used: 0},
            {slots: 0, used: 0},
            {slots: 0, used: 0},
            {slots: 0, used: 0},
            {slots: 0, used: 0},
            {slots: 0, used: 0}
        ]
    }
  }
```

Reducer:

```
switch (action.type) {
  case actions.SET_SPELL_SLOTS:    
    let newSpellSlotArray = state.profiles[state.selectedProfileId].spellSlots.slice();

    newSpellSlotArray.map((item, index) => {
      if (index !== action.spellslot-1) {
        return item
      }

      let newItem = {
        ...item,
        slots: parseInt(action.count)
      };
      console.log("Updating item:", item, newItem);

      return newItem;
    })

    var newState = {
      ...state,
      profiles: {
        ...state.profiles,
        [state.selectedProfileId]:{
          ...state.profiles[state.selectedProfileId],
          spellSlots: newSpellSlotArray
        }
      }
    }

    console.log((newState == state))

    return newState
  default:
    return state
}
```

Console logs:

```
Updating item: {slots: 0, used: 0}
   slots: 0
   used: 0
 __proto__: Object 
{slots: 5, used: 0}
    slots: 5
    used: 0
    __proto__: Object
spellbookData.js:70
false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reducer is broken, because you're not actually saving the array with the new values.

- `spellSlots.slice()` will indeed create a new array reference with all the old values
- However, `newSpellSlotArray.map()` returns a new array reference containing all the values returned by the `map()` callback, but your code is currently throwing away that new array by not assigning it to a variable.
- In the return statement, `spellSlots: newSpellSlotArray` is going to return a new array containing all the old data, not the updated data.

The short-term fix for your code would be:

```js
const newSpellSlotArray = state.profiles[state.selectedProfileId].spellSlots.map( (item, index) => {
  // map logic here
});
```

However, I'd strongly encourage you to [switch to using our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org).  RTK's `createSlice` API uses Immer internally, which lets you write "mutating" immutable updates.  That would let you simplify this whole reducer down to:

```js
const profilesSlice= createSlice({
  name: "profiles",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    spellSlotsUpdated(state, action) {
      const {spellslot, count} = action.payload;
      const item = state.profiles[state.selectedProfileId].spellSlots[spellslot- 1];
      item.slots = parseInt(count);
    }
  }  
})
```

As you can see, that's much shorter and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

> Modify your Reducer, Array.map() returns new array which you have to store and use

```
switch (action.type) {
  case actions.SET_SPELL_SLOTS:    
    let newSpellSlotArray = state.profiles[state.selectedProfileId].spellSlots.map((item, index) => {
      if (index !== action.spellslot-1) {
        return item
      }

      let newItem = {
        ...item,
        slots: parseInt(action.count)
      };
      console.log("Updating item:", item, newItem);

      return newItem;
    })

    var newState = {
      ...state,
      profiles: {
        ...state.profiles,
        [state.selectedProfileId]:{
          ...state.profiles[state.selectedProfileId],
          spellSlots: newSpellSlotArray
        }
      }
    }

    console.log((newState == state))

    return newState
  default:
    return state
}
```